# Does radiant barrier work if hidden under timber structure

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conduction

I am insulating my house roof and I wanted to explore the radiant barrier and if these are actually effective in a real life scenario.

The desired outcome of installing such barrier, would be to effectively limit heat accumulation (lower temperature) in the rooms of an attic.

Consider the following. The structure of the roof is made up of concrete tiles (about $2$ cm thick), tile battens, roof breathable membrane, $32$ mm thick wood boards, rafters $20$ cm $\times$ $8$ cm.

I was thinking of installing $20$ um aluminium foil with a $20$ mm air gap between wood boards and $20$ mm air gap between mineral wool insulation all in between rafters.

Would such aluminium foil be effective in reflecting radiant heat out, despite the fact that its not directly exposed to sun light.

Is it possible to calculate effectiveness of such a radiant barrier? I understand that some heat will be conducted, via material (i.e the rafters) into the attic.